# Error in distGeo regarding longitude data

Tags: r, geosphere

I have an error using distGeo with this code

```
zone <- zone %>% rowwise() %>% 
mutate(distance = distGeo(c(long,lat), c(longitude,latitude))/1000)
```

The error is the following :
Caused by error in `.pointsToMatrix()`:
! longitude < -360

I have indeed a longitude < 0 (but not <-360) but this is normal

Here an extract of my data

[image]

Do you know what could have happened ?

Thank you

Comment: Please try to make your question reproducible for others, i.e. use output from `dput(zone)` or `dput(head(zone))` instead / in addition to screenshot of your dataframe, also make sure your reproducible example fails the same way as your main project  / script. BTW, `longitude` in error message does not refer to the column named `longitude`, it's a hardcoded error message triggered by the minimum value of the 1st column of point matrix and might as well be caused by your `long` column - https://github.com/rspatial/geosphere/blob/6b4a6b2380b574ac999bc6bb0b950f0acdd9dc0b/R/pointsToMatrix.R#L51

Comment: The error is caused by this: "c(long, lat)" and "c(longitude, latitude)".  This represents 2 vectors not two data frames with a longitude and latitude columns.  Also it is unlikely you need the `rowwise()` call.  Edit the question and post the results of `dput(head(zone))` and someone can provide sample code.